# Allow / Deny screen rotation in onConfigurationChange() - Android

Tags: android

I have an activity that handles 2 modes of display :

1. Normal mode : The screen should not rotate, always in portrait mode.
2. Fullscreen mode : The screen could be portrait or landscape

I have only 1 activity to handle the 2 modes with :

1. boolean variable `isFullscreen()` that indicates either the `Activity` is in fullscreen mode or normal mode.
2. `changeMode()` calls `setContentView()` to switch the XML layout proper to the current mode
3. in the manifest file, i have `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` to let the `Activity` handle configuration change
4. overriding the method `onConfigurationChanged()`.

I've tried this :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (isFullscreen) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    } else {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

but in this case : the screet does not rotate in any mode (not even in fullscreen mode, with `isFullscreen()` et to true)

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (isFullscreen) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    } else {

    }
}
```

But I got `Super Not Called exception` or something like that (I was thinking if i don't call super in the case of normal mode, it would not rotate the screen)

And finally, I've tried this :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (isFullscreen) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    } else {
        newConfig.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are toggling fullscreen call this don't do it in onConfigurationChanged

code:

```
if(isFullscreen){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}else{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: cooool this worked for me!! very nice!! i also need to call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); in onCreate too.. thnx man